# CodeIgniter helper not loading

Tags: codeigniter, helper

I was trying to use this helper to create a country drop down list.(https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/helper-dropdown-country-code)

I created a file called `country_helper.php` with the helper code inside, in my controller I'm loading that helper with `$this->load->helper('country_helper');`

But when using `country_dropdown();` I'm getting the following error:

```
Call to undefined function country_dropdown() in /Users/wouter/Sites/socialagent.me/application/controllers/user.php on line 299
```

Comment: where you put your `country_helper.php`?

Comment: @pktangyue in `/application/helpers`

Comment: I tried, and it works fine. Can your load system helper correctly?

Comment: I can autoload them, but it seems when I use `$this->load->helper('country_helper');` it's not loading it

Comment: Maybe you can show your full controller code, and I may find what's going wrong.

Comment: Well there's really not much happening now right now as I was just testing, in my `__construct()' I'm trying to load the helper '$this->load->helper('country_helper');' and using it in `index()`

Comment: do you add `parent::__construct()` in your `__construct()`

Comment: Good you mentioned that, I accidentally wrote `__contruct()` instead of `__construct()`, can you post that as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {   
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('country_helper');
        echo country_dropdown();
    }   
    public function index()
    {
    }    
}
```

I tried this code, and it works fine.

Comment: you don't use country_helper, you always omit country_helper and .php when loading helpers, see http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html about loading a helper.

Answer (score 2):

You need better set helpers function globaly. Find file application/config/autoload.php and set

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('country');
```

Answer (score 1):

using:
`$this->load->helper('country');`

not:
`$this->load->helper('country_helper');`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is to add the following to your composer.json file. For eg: after "require": {
}

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "application/helpers/<YOUR_HELPER_FILE_NAME>.php"
    ]
},
```

After that, you need to run `composer dump-autoload`

This will autoload your helper file. You don't have to load it manually.